# How to display a non matching value also?

Tags: ms-access

USING VB6 AND MS-ACCESS 2003

So on…,

TABLE 1

```
EMPID DATE     

101 22-07-2009 
201 22-07-2009 
501 22-07-2009  
301 23-07-2009
401 23-07-2009
501 23-07-2009
101 24-07-2009
501 24-07-2009
```

So on…,

From the above table two tables I want to display all EMP ids for the date wise

Expected Output

```
EMPID  DATE

101 22-07-2009
201 22-07-2009
301 
401 
501 22-07-2009
101
201
301 23-07-2009
401 23-07-2009
501 23-07-2009
101 24-07-2009
201
301
401
501 24-07-2009
```

So on…,

Need Query Help.

Comment: Gopal you have already asked a question like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1220659/how-to-display-all-ids-for-the-selected-date

Comment: @mlevit - Check that question, This is different from that one.

Comment: When you say "using VB6 and Access 2003" do you mean that you're using an MDB created in A2003? If so, Access is not really involved in your question.

Comment: am Not mentioned any MDB in that posted question.

Comment: Still am not get a proper answer. can any one help to solve my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Haven't executed to verify for sure, but this should get you most of the way there:

```
SELECT
    AllPossibleCardEvents.PersonId, 
    AllPossibleCardEvents.EmpName,
    AllPossibleCardEvents.TitleCode,
    AllPossibleCardEvents.TitleName,
    AllPossibleCardEvents.CardEventDate, 
    ActualCardEvents.CardEventDate AS MatchingCardEventDate
FROM
    (
        (
            SELECT
                p.PersonId, 
                p.EmpName,
                p.TitleCode,
                p.TitleName,
                AllDates.CardEventDate
            FROM
                (SELECT DISTINCT CardEventDate FROM T_Cardevent) AllDates, 
                T_Person p
        ) AllPossibleCardEvents
        LEFT OUTER JOIN T_Cardevent ActualCardEvents ON 
            AllPossibleCardEvents.PersonId = Actual.PersonId AND 
            AllPossibleCardEvents.CardEventDate = Actual.CardEventDate
    )
```

Where "MatchingCardEventDate" will be NULL for records that are NOT actual events.  For actual events, the value of "MatchingCardEventDate" will be the valid date.

Hope this helps.

Comment: @Chris. Happy with your answer, I edited my question. Can you modify your answer for the one table, am not using two tables

Comment: @Gopal : Glad the answer is helping so far.  You still have the two tables for T_Person and T_Cardevent, correct?  The other "tables" such as AllPossibleCardEvents and ActualCardEvents are just labeled/aliases and do not need to be actual tables.  Am I understanding your question?

Comment: @Chris. Is working Fine. But i want to select empname, titlecode, titlename column also, How to modify you query. Help me

Comment: @Gopal : Assuming you want these values on all records (even if no matching event), then you can add those columns to both the inner SELECT to get "AllPossibleCardEvents" as well as the outer SELECT that generates the report columns.  I have updated the query above to include this change.

Answer (score 2):

Without questioning your data model, to get the results you want you will need a third table (which I will call Dates) You need a Cross Join on Table 1 and Dates, which will give a result of all employees for all days. Then you need to Left Join to EmpID and Date. 
The Left Join will include all of the results from the first join but only the matching rows from Table 2 will be populated. Access is funny in how it handles query structure, also it does not support the SQL-92 `CROSS JOIN` syntax, but it would look something like the below.

```
SELECT t1.EmpID, t2.Date 
  FROM (
        SELECT t1.EmpID, d.Date 
          FROM [Table 1] AS t1, 
               Dates AS d
       ) AS DT1
       LEFT OUTER JOIN [Table 2] AS t2 
          ON DT1.EmpID = t2.EmpID 
             AND DT1.Date = t2.Date
 ORDER 
    BY DT1.Date, DT1.EmpID;
```